# Assistance with dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to use this dictionary in order to conduct a "check" based on the user input. So for instance it would be along the lines of something like it is used below. I think it might need to use a "For" loop?  I am improving the question due to people not understanding it. The 1st code is what I am attempting to accomplish using the dictionary to provide result of the 2nd code below.

```
levels = {
    'Closet': {'South': 'Hangar'},
    'Hangar': {'North': 'Closet', 'East': 'Westwood'},
    'Westwood': {'West': 'Hangar'}
}

location = "Closet"
direction = input()

if location == ("Checking dictionary to see which location it is")
    if direction == ("Checking dictionary to see if direction is applicable")
       location = ("updated location based on direction used with what is in dictionary levels")
```

i.e

```
if location == "Closet"
    if direction == "South"
        location = "Hangar"
        choices = "North" or "East"
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what your question is. Is your question "do I need to use a for loop"?

Comment: I think instead of asking another question about the same problem, you should improve your existing question to make it more clear, if it isn't clear enough.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to use the dictionary terms associated with the "if" statements during a while loop 

So for instance, it would say what the value is based on what the key is and also compare the location of current location with the dictionary and directions implemented with user to the values of the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```py
if levels.get(location):
    possible_direction = levels.get(location)
    if possible_direction.get(direction):
          location = possible_direction.get(direction)
```

Or even:

```py
new_location = levels.get(location, {}).get(direction)
if new_location:
     location = new_location
```

Or even:

```py
try:
    location = levels[location][direction]
except BaseException:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a stab at what you are looking for here.

```
def update_location(location, direction, data):
   return data.get('location', {}).get(direction, None)

levels = {
   'Closet': {'South': 'Hangar'}, 
   'Hangar': {'North': 'Closet', 'East': 'Westwood'}, 
   'Westwood': {'West': 'Hangar'} 
}
location = 'Closet'
direction = 'South'
tmp = update_location(location, direction, levels)
if tmp is not None:
   location = tmp
```

It's a dictionary.  You don't need to iterate over it to look for a key inside it.  You just access the key.  The function above will return None if the values passed in are not in the passed in dictionary.